# Is there any fast way to remove an element from a string array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
    array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, array[i]);
```

This is working for int array, not for `String` array...
Is there any fast way to remove an element from a string array in `Java`?

Comment: Java arrays are immutable, and `ArrayUtils` appears to be a custom class.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? There is no "fast" way to remove an element from an array, if you do not want to use `ArrayUtils`... writing a method yourself isn't too slow.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch `ArrayUtils` is an Apache commons class

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are using `org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils` class, which is not standard Java class but part of Apache Commons Lang library. If you know an index of element, it would be more efficient to use

```
array = ArrayUtils.remove(array, i);
```

As this version will not search for given element, just remove by index. This should work for object arrays (including `String` array) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since array can not be resized, it may create some problems (eg.- raise of cost) when you try to remove some element from an array.
In this case  `ArrayList` would be a better alternative. You can add/remove element from `ArryList` more continently  -

```
List<String> strgs = new ArrayList<String>();
strgs.add("first");
strgs.add("second");
strgs.add("third");

strgs.remove("second");
```